# Find the max value from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is the array:

```
largestNumber([1,19,[3,7],16,[19,27,12],13,11]);
```

I am trying to find the max value using Javascript function but not getting the solution.

Anyone could help me to get the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "trying". Where's your current code that is failing to do what you want?

Comment: @Jonas: How do you figure that question is asking the same thing as this one?

Comment: @crazy Train the OP has shown no effort whatsoever, i gave him a good starting point.

Comment: There are probably thousands of solutions for this, its a common codegolf / codewars task

Comment: @JonasW.: I agree that no effort is shown and IMO, it should be closed. That doesn't make it a duplicate.

Comment: @crazy train it takes longer to get 10 closevotes for "unclear what you are asking", which gives people enough time to answer...

Comment: @JonasW.: It doesn't take 10 votes. Yeah, he's abusing the site, but aren't you also by using an invalid reason for closing?

Comment: @crazy train close votes are totally democratic :) if you disagree, you can vote to reopen ...

Comment: @JonasW.: You're subverting the democratic nature of close votes by imposing an invalid reason for closing.

Comment: ...funny thing is that you're complaining that the OP showed no effort, but neither did you. There are may valid duplicates if you'd only use the same Google search that the OP ought to have used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Math.max` and spread syntax `...`

```js
const largestNumber = arr => Math.max(...[].concat(...arr));
console.log(largestNumber([1,19,[3,7],16,[19,27,12],13,11]))
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Is there any way using function, we can find the max value?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking.